# Makefile with scipt creating temporary file not found

Tags: makefile

I have a code that I compile on my computer and on the server of our university.
the code works without memory errors on my computer(I did the tests with valgrind), but with computers of our university I have this message in photo:[makefile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6kXU.png)
I saw in [the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL7Mt.png) they gave us, that they're creating a temporary file that makes the script end with failure and exit 1.
Do you know why this file is not created or what is the source of the problem?

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow. Please do not provide the error messages or the source code of your script as pictures. Copy-paste them in your question and format them using the `{}` button.

Comment: If you run the script directly, without the makefile, does the error still occur? Do you have access to `linkdirectory/` on the university computers?

Comment: It was another problem, the inode number of / and /tmp and /adhome were the same, so a problem occured. I fixed it thanks !